# Why is my React rendering twice after my state is declared?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

My React project seems to render everything twice (I noticed after calling console.log and getting it 2x)  it seems to be happening when I first declare state in my App, a log before the state renders ones a log after 2x.

Additionally componentDidMount after the state is declared renders only once

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getProteins } from "./services/proteinsService";
import ProteinBuilder from "./containers/ProteinToolbar/ProteinBuilder.jsx";
import BlendOutput from "./containers/BlendOutput/BlendOutput";
import "./App.css";

console.log("App before state");
class App extends Component {
  state = { proteins: getProteins() };
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
  }

  render() {
    console.log("App after state");
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">Nav</div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col col-sm-3">
            <ProteinBuilder proteins={this.state.proteins} />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-9">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-12 BlendOutput  border rounded">
                <BlendOutput proteins={this.state.proteins} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My getProteins() pulls from the following:

```
const proteins = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "Pea Protein Isolate",
    description: "Pea Protein Isolate",
    digestibility: 0.98,
    AA: {
      His: 2.5,
      Ile: 4.5,
      Leu: 8.4,
      Lys: 7.2,
      MetCys: 2.1,
      PheTyr: 9.3,
      Thr: 3.9,
      Trp: 1,
      Val: 5
    },
    percentOfBlend: 0.382
  },

  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "Texturized Pea Protein",
    description: "Texturized Pea Protein",
    digestibility: 0.94,
    AA: {
      His: 2.0,
      Ile: 3.91,
      Leu: 6.84,
      Lys: 5.96,
      MetCys: 2.69,
      PheTyr: 7.31,
      Thr: 3.02,
      Trp: 0.84,
      Val: 4.23
    },
    percentOfBlend: 0.448
  },

  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "Sacha Inchi Protein",
    description: "Sacha Inchi",
    digestibility: 0.92,
    AA: {
      His: 2.6,
      Ile: 5,
      Leu: 6.4,
      Lys: 4.3,
      MetCys: 3.7,
      PheTyr: 7.9,
      Thr: 4.3,
      Trp: 2.9,
      Val: 4
    },
    percentOfBlend: 0.17
  },

  {
    _id: 4,
    name: "Potato Protein",
    description: "Potato protein isolate",
    digestibility: 0.95,
    AA: {
      His: 1.7,
      Ile: 5.6,
      Leu: 9.2,
      Lys: 7.1,
      MetCys: 3.2,
      PheTyr: 11.6,
      Thr: 4.4,
      Trp: 1.4,
      Val: 8
    },
    percentOfBlend: 0.0
  }
];

export function getProteins() {
  return proteins;
}

export function multiplyProteins() {
  proteins.map(proteins.AA.map());
}
```

Comment: you get `App after state` two times?

Comment: Yeah `App after state` logs twice, and `App before state` once

Comment: you said your app rendering twice? have you checked if the issue is from parent component? it can render children twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a simplified version of your case in the snippet below, and did not see the same behavior if `setState` was never called. Therefore I think the problem is among one of:

- a child component is calling setState, and causing a re-render
- a parent component is causing a re-render
- you have [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) enabled.

This snippet gives a break down of what happens during the render lifecycle. Comment out the section that sets state, and you have an example that should be the same as what you posted, minus child components.

```js
console.log("create App component");
function setFoo(){console.log('setting foo'); return 'bar'}
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { foo: setFoo() };
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount. Current state", this.state);
    this.setState(
      {qux: 'quo'}, 
      () => console.log('setState callback (set state has been fully applied) has state', this.state)
    )
    console.log("componentDidMount -> this.setState() was called (but may not have been applied). Current state", this.state)
  }

  render() {
    console.log("App.render() with state", this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

console.log('before dom render')
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
console.log('after dom render')
```

```html
<div id="app" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to experiment with the snippet, you may also want to try calling `setState` multiple times in a row, and seeing what happens to the state after each call.

Comment: My index.js had:
`
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
`
-I changed them to fragments but I am still getting a doubled render.  
-I am not calling setState() in any child components at the moment.

so would it be something else in my parent component?

Comment: Yeah, it's gotta be something subtle in your setup, I would think. `React.Fragment` shouldn't cause a double render, but `React.StrictMode` definitely does. If you are only getting one double render, it's probably ok to ignore, but there is a chance that you end up with performance issues later down the line (if your total render cycle gets complicated enough, and since this is top-level, it matters more). I'd try removing portions of code, being if that changes it, then putting them back and removing something else if you really want to track the issue down.

Comment: The main takeaway though is that react calls render pretty liberally, and it's designed so that it can call render whenever it needs to at minimal cost, if you make render have no side-effects.

Comment: One other thing you could try is double check with a prod build of react, if you are using a dev build. Sometimes dev functionality does stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

`proteins: getProteins()` is not advisable.
I suggest you do this:

`componentDidMount(){
   this.setState({proteins: getProteins()});
}`

and the `render()` method is called whenever you update the state or the props is changed.

Comment: This doesn't create the state properly for me, when I use this the children components have null for their props.  Should I use a different lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 0):

React calls some methods like render method twice to help programmers catch bad practices like API calls and other side effects in wrong methods.

ComponentDidMount is the right place to do side-effects therefore React calls it one time.

For more information check here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Comment: That's a neat feature I was unaware of, but it isn't active by default. You have to use the `StrictMode` component and wrap the part of the app you want to check. Since I doubt the OP is using this component, this is probably not the issue here.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Actually React may call render method for an arbitrary amount of times without any obvious reason, programmers should program in a way that this doesn't break anything. But since he said two times, I think my answer will help him.

Comment: Agreed, and hence bad practice to make render non-idempotent (have side effects), but the question here is "why", and this is not the reason (afaik).

Comment: hmm, I did have StrictMode activated.  I disabled it though and I'm still having issues.  One issue is when I loop over some elements they are creating duplicate key values which throws an error

Comment: @HPylori As I told you, React doesn't guarantee the number of times it may call render method. you have to code in a way that this doesn't create an issue. I advise you to close this question cause you found the reason for multiple renderings. then open another question and share your new problem with its error message. you can share your question link here so I can take look at it.